# get all rows of a pagination table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-table

I'm using datatable in **bootstrap4**  and I've a *pagination* table (10 itens per pag).
I made a function to get values in table, but
when I tring to get all rows values, I've one problem because I only get the values show in a screen.
I tryed used in js ,
document.getElementById("myTable).tBodies[0].rows;
and tried Jquery
but always I get only the values in screen.
Has anyone had such a problem?

Comment: You need to access the `DataTable` element that you created. https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().data()

Comment: Are you using [tag:jquery-datatables]?  Or [bootstrap-table.com](https://bootstrap-table.com/)

Comment: For bootstrap-table, use [getData](https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/api/methods/#getdata) `$table.bootstrapTable('getData').`

Comment: @freedomn-m, thanks for the answer, I using [link](bootstrap-table.com) and my table is like this <table id="datatable" class="table .table-striped table-bordered table-responsive-md">

Comment: @RobbieJW, Hey man cheers, I'm reading the documentation and trying . thanks for the help, if a finish the work I'll tell to you !

Comment: @freedomn-m I'ts funny because I got ".bootstrapTable is not a function" and I "installed" bootstrap4 using composer and I using to make a css and everything is worked correct .

Answer (score 1):

I used
$('#table').DataTable().[data().row()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().data()) ;
and it works but when I iterate this bring me a values like a "innerHTML" but I have functions in a rows(), so I need get values like a "innerText" because this is a values show in screen.

Thanks guys, I appreciate your help.

Comment: Hey guys I solved the problem.
I'll give all context
 I had one table with n rows in m pages, my user will use a filter to select x rows 
but I only got the first page. 
my solution was in 2 lines in javascript

var myTable = table.DataTable();
myTable.page.len(-1).draw();

and it's done. 

thanks guys !!